# How to hide `org.eclipse.ui.editors` on the basis of perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

Suppose I have two perspective. In which my application has two different `org.eclipse.ui.editors` as following.

- Perpsective1

  - Editor1
- Perspective2

  - Editor2

When I switch from Perspective1 to Perspective2 My application should hide all the Editor1 opened instances should get invisible and only Editor2 type should be visible and vice versa.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Open editors are not normally affected by perspective changes so you would have to code this yourself.

You can use an `IPerspectiveListener` (or the extended `IPerspectiveListener4`) to be notified about perspective changes.

The perspective listener is added using `IWorkbenchWindow.addPerspectiveListener`

Comment: Editor area is same for Editor1 and Editor2 I would like to have only one type of Editor should be open at time. I found `iWorkbenchPage.setEditorAreaVisible()` Which hides editor area. However which does not satisfies my requirement. I want to hide one type of Editor in some perspective and another should be visible. Same time hidden Editors should be visible when we switch to that perspective.

Comment: You can't hide editors, you will have to open and close them in the perspective listener.

Comment: By using iWorkbenchPage.hideEditor( iEditorReference ); I can hide it but once it is hide it Removes an open editor, turn it into a non-participating editor. So i will not be able to recollect all the editors which are closed during switch.

Comment: `IWorkbenchPage.hideEditor` is not supported by Eclipse 4.3 and does nothing.

Comment: Is there a way to save the state of opened editors while switching the perspective so that we can get that state and reopen the hidden editors just like memonto.

Comment: The Workbench has a way to save the editor state for shutdown / restart but this is not available as an API.